# How does the normalization of Square Difference work? (TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

From [OpenCV matchTemplate](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html) (TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) :

$$
R(x,y) = \frac
 {\sum_{x',y'}{(T(x',y') - I(x+x',y+y'))^2}}
 {\underbrace{
   \sqrt{\sum_{x',y'}{T(x',y')^2}*\sum_{x',y'}{I(x+x',y+y')^2}}
  }_{\text{Where does this come from?}}}
$$

I don't understand where the normalization expression comes from and how does it work?

Does it intend to make $R(x,y) \in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:algebra-precalculus]?

Comment: I’ve seen previous topics talking about summation in this topic so I was hoping it would go well. Sorry, can you advice me a good topic for my question?